# Columna tipo Text no acepta valores default en migracion Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, migracion

***Laravel 9.17.0***

Buenas, estoy haciendo una migracion de una tabla, y al momento de ejecutarla me da un error en esta linea

```
$table->text('token')->default("No body");
```

como puedo añadir un valor por defecto a este tipo de columnas?, es el campo que me da problemas, ya que necesito que este campo se llene con algun texto por defecto, es de tipo text ya que recibirá una cadena bastante larga, aproximadamente de 400-500 caracteres, el campo token puede considerarse tambien como nullable, probe de esta forma y tampoco dio resultado:

```
$table->text('token')->nullable()->default("No Content");
```

O que alternativa puedo optar?

mi migracion es esta:

```
Schema::create('sucursals', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('cod_sucursal')->unsigned();
            $table->string('description')->default('No description');
            $table->string('address')->default("No set");
            $table->string('phone',40)->default("No set");
            $table->string('codSys',30)->default("No set");
            $table->bigInteger('numberState')->default(0);
            $table->text('token')->default("tokenasdf");
```

El error que me lanza la migracion es:

```
 Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1101 BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY or JSON column 'token' can't have a default value (SQL: create table `sucursals` (`id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `cod_sucursal` int unsigned not null, `description` varchar(255) not null default 'No description', `address` varchar(255) not null default 'No set', `phone` varchar(40) not null default 'No set', `codSys` varchar(30) not null default 'No set', `nit` bigint not null default '0', `token` text null default 'tokenasdf'.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto no es un *"problema"* de Laravel, sino del motor de base de datos que no permite valores por defecto para algunos tipos de datos. De la [documentación oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-type-defaults.html):

> #### The BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY, and JSON data types cannot be assigned a default value.
>
> ... If a data type specification includes no explicit DEFAULT value, MySQL determines the default value as follows:
> If the column can take NULL as a value, the column is defined with an explicit DEFAULT NULL clause.

En resumen: Las columnas de tipo BLOB, TEXT, GEOMETRY y JSON no permiten que se asigne un valor por defecto, a menos que este sea NULL.

Si la columna puede contener un valor nulo, automáticamente será definida con una cláusula explícita `DEFAULT NULL`, por lo que puedes usar simplemente:

```
$table->text('token')->nullable();
```

El valor por defecto para esta columna será `NULL` y ya no tendrás problemas para crear la tabla.

Comment: Muchas gracias Triby, tienes razón, eso de no leer la documentación..... xd